# React Converting db data to object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, antd

I am creating a simple website using React and node js. I load data from my mongo db data store. And I am using ant design to draw a graph on my web site.

I am trying to draw a graph from `@ant-design/charts` and from the sample it requires data like below.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Line } from '@ant-design/charts';
const Page: React.FC = () => {
  const data = [
    { year: '1991', value1: 3 },
    { year: '1992', value: 4 },
    { year: '1993', value: 3.5 },
    { year: '1994', value: 5 },
    { year: '1995', value: 4.9 },
    { year: '1996', value: 6 },
    { year: '1997', value: 7 },
    { year: '1998', value: 9 },
    { year: '1999', value: 13 },
  ];
  const config = {
    data,
    height: 400,
    xField: 'year',
    yField: 'value',
    point: {
      size: 5,
      shape: 'diamond',
    },
    label: {
      style: {
        fill: '#aaa',
      },
    },
  };
  return <Line {...config} />;
};
export default Page;
```

The data that I want to load is below.

[image]

I have successfully loaded by data but I have failed to display on the website. **Here is my question how can I form my loaded data, which is array, into the form of what ant design want me to do so...?**

This is the code that I used to load data from mongo db.

```js
  const [ readPageList, setReadPageList ] = useState([]);
  var bookId = "60219f2a03fdf00d5cf4051d" 

  useEffect(()=>{
    axios.get('/api/books/GetBookById/'+bookId)
    .then( response => {
      setReadPageList(response.data.book.dailyPage);
    })
  },[])

  const dataList = readPageList.map((pages,index) => {
    return [JSON.stringify({year:index, value:pages.readPage})]


  })
```

So I try to use dataList instead of data in ant design graph

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First you check what type of data they are for this you can use:

```
console.log(typeof data)
```

if it display string you can convert to it to object simply writing:

```
JSON.parse(data) // it will convert data to object
```

if not you can try to convert it to an string and convert back to object like the code bellow:

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))
```

Maybe you can write the code down below:

```
...
if ( typeof data === `string` )
   data = JSON.parse(data)
...
```